# Can't get image to show inside div with bg-image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm currently working on http://dawtano.com/pp/ , and I want to show off my work in the div's looking like two pieces of paper on top of each other, with an  inside. But something is going wrong - I'm currently working out from the same code used on http://bestwebgallery.com (thumbnail-view) - I can't get the image to show inside, no matter what size or w/e, I'm lost.

Comment: You should try to post excerpts from your code instead of sending people off to fish it out of public websites.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really figured this site out yet, and didnt want to post a huge load of code in normal format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
<img src"http://dawtano.com/pp/images/qillnet-s.png" alt="Qill.net" />
```

with

```
<img src="http://dawtano.com/pp/images/qillnet-s.png" alt="Qill.net" />
```

You forgot to put an "=" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

in css it's background-image perhaps that's the problem?
try `css="background-image:url('paper.png');"`